# Handler for hooking into Java's TLS/SSL connection

Tags: java

I'd like to be able to hook into the TLS/SSL connection handshake that takes place when I create a secure connection from Java to a server. I know that I can add the VM argument `-Djavax.net.debug=all` which will output a lot of content, but I would like to to able to log each 'send' and 'received' message going back and forward. Is this possible?

Comment: For what purpose? Debugging? Why not use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: you can minimize the output using this VM argument `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake `

Comment: @Boris: Because I want my application to be able to tell me if and when it changes handshake - just to name one scenario.

Comment: @Pradeepa Thanks. I was not aware of this option.